# What are the keys accepted by openSSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, key-authentication

**Question** is simple:

> What are the (private) key *types* and (their *specification* - format, syntax) accepted by current **openSSH**?

The vague answer "the keys generated by `ssh-keygen`" is not accepted - I know it. They are called PEM with such headers (RSA, DSA, ECDSA variations):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The other format is described in [PROTOCOL.key](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/PROTOCOL.key) and is extension by `openssh`. It is also used as a default for `Ed25519` keys, as stated in manual and (regardless passphrase) marked with header:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

There are also legacy `RSA1` keys that should be gone today with SSHv1 protocol, but can be identified by the header:

```
SSH PRIVATE KEY FILE FORMAT 1.1
```

Are there any others? I am searching for more verbose description of other keys. I didn't find it (so far) explicitly specified in any manual page nor in any RFC for SSH.

The **bonus question** (not needed to answer, but I would appreciate the insight):

> What is the reason behind (`openssh`) decoding every dummy file and asking for a passphrase, even if it does not have the proper header?

---

*Footnote:* Question was originally posted on [openssh-unix-dev list](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2015-December/034617.html), but so far without any answer so I am trying this awesome community, if there is somebody able to answer it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'header'? The `-----BEGIN` and `-----END`strings are merely encapsulation boundaries (EB) with an included comment. The actual info is found in the base64 serialized structure in between. Without having checked the source code, I'd guess the text in the EBs is ignored by openssh that only tries to decode whatever is in between. The ciphername and KDF info should indicate what are types of the actual keys stored in the structure. I'd also guess these are open to future values and there's no fixed list.

Comment: Yes. By header I meant the EB, as you corrected me. If I am right from my reading code in past, the first guess is based on the filename, then these EB's and if all the previous fails, it tries to decode it somehow. The details are still unknown for me because I was too lazy to go so deeper in the code, but there will not probably be any other option. The `openssh` key is documented, them PEM has also RFC specification and it is probably all. If `openssh` reads something that does not make sense or is not base64, it should probably error out, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could you add in the description exactly what your trying and how you test it? Details should appear in debug/verbose modes. - Anyway - You can take a look at `sshkey.c`. In `sshkey_parse_private_fileblob_type()`, you can see all the supported key types (for now). If the key type is unspecified, `sshkey_parse_private2()` will do all the checks you're expecting it to do, but if it fails and OpenSSL is enabled, `sshkey_parse_private_pem_fileblob()` is called and will use OpenSSL's `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey()` to parse the data and if that fails too, it assumes the wrong passphrase was given.

Comment: I am most interested in the "bonus question" as posted above. Minimal testing case is just `ssh-add <()`, which repetitively asks for passphrase for empty file. It is at least weird. I got with my code inspection to the `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey()`, which was for me black box. As I browse through man page I see the only result from this function is `NULL`, regardless the reason (parse error? or wrong passphrase, else?). This is probably the root cause of described behaviour. If I am right, there should be some way of getting the reason of failure through the api and decide regarding to that.

Comment: It all gets done here `https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c`, where  `PEM_read_bio()` reads the file data and makes the necessary checks, for example it registers a failure reason `PEM_R_NO_START_LINE` when the first read returns no bytes. Is it possible to read this error in `openssh::sshkey.c`? Not sure. - Anyway, the current behaviour is explained. Is the question now if the implementation can change to return a failure reason, thus becoming a bit more user friendly?

Comment: @forcefsck Thanks. Feel free to sum these findings in the answer. It is not exactly what I expect, but you moved me a bit further and the behaviour is explained. I plan to give it some try during January to see what can be done between `openssh` and `openssl` (or you can if you have some ideas - patch is always welcomed).

Comment: Are the down-voters brave enough to write what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The most helpful comments from @forcefsck. Unfortunately he didn't fill the answer so I was unable to award the bounty. In short, the answer is **PEM** + **RSA1** + new openSSH format which is described in the question and the main problem was with PEM.

## The long one & Bonus

OpenSSH is using parser from openSSL (`PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey()`), which has the only return value for all the failures (`NULL`) and if it fails, openSSH expects it was because of wrong passphrase.

### Without OpenSSL

I just tried to build OpenSSH without OpenSSL support (`--without-openssl` configure option) and the behaviour is "correct":

```
# ./ssh-add <(echo "")
Error loading key "/dev/fd/63": invalid format
```

### Fix with OpenSSL

The other thing is how to fix it. The poke comes from `ERR_get_error()` function and their friends which should allow us to distinguish between different errors.

#### Wrong passphrase errors

```
# ./ssh-add /tmp/rsa
140480353842840:error:0906A068:lib(9):func(106):reason(104):pem_lib.c:457:
Enter passphrase for /tmp/rsa: 
140480353842840:error:06065064:lib(6):func(101):reason(100):evp_enc.c:592:
140480353842840:error:0906A065:lib(9):func(106):reason(101):pem_lib.c:482:
```

Reasons: `PEM_R_BAD_PASSWORD_READ`, `PEM_R_BAD_BASE64_DECODE`, `PEM_R_BAD_DECRYPT`.

#### Parse error codes

```
# ./ssh-add <(echo "")
139656018548376:error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108):pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

or this:

```
140654301202072:error:0906D066:lib(9):func(109):reason(102):pem_lib.c:809:
```

Reason: `PEM_R_NO_START_LINE`, `PEM_R_BAD_END_LINE`, but there might be more possibilities.

#### Solution?

Adding some more checks for OpenSSL errors should give us an option to choose which error we want to mark as "format" error and which is "bad passphrase". This is located in function `sshkey_parse_private_pem_fileblob()` in `sshkey.c` on line around 3800.

```
unsigned long e = ERR_get_error();
if (ERR_GET_REASON(e) == PEM_R_NO_START_LINE ||
    ERR_GET_REASON(e) == PEM_R_BAD_END_LINE) {
        r = SSH_ERR_INVALID_FORMAT;
} else {
        r = SSH_ERR_KEY_WRONG_PASSPHRASE;
}
```