# constant "enter passphrase for public key" by ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

What could be the reason that **ssh < host >** is asking for public key password

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa.pub':
```

even if provided a good password?

I have no problem with pkcs11 pam module login when I specific a provider
and I have no problem when I add key via `ssh-add`

100% it's a client side problem
could be that ssh agent is catching request?

*Do you mean, that you're constantly asked for the password, and not even the correct password is accepted? What exactly do you mean with "when i specific a provider" .. ? gerhard d*

```
$ ssh {host}
Enter passphrase for key '/home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
Permission denied (publickey).


$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ ssh {host}
logged in
```

after reboot I can't ssh as enter passphrase failed but I can add key to agent or ssh via pkcs11

```
$ ssh -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so {host}
Enter PIN for 'PIV_II (PIV Card Holder pin)': 
...
logged in
```

ps. distro = debian sid , %d is my home folder

### solution -> change ssh config entry:

**as Jakuje wrote the problem was in wrong ssh config file entry**

```
# ~/.ssh/config

Host {host}
    IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub   # should be ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Do you mean, that you're constantly asked for the password, and not even the correct password is accepted? What exactly do you mean with "when i specific a provider" .. ?

Comment: @gerhardd. see edit

Comment: Related to the continuous asking for a passphrase: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251194/what-are-the-keys-accepted-by-openssh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have in your `ssh_config` in `~/.ssh/config` a line like

```
Host *
  IdentityFile /home/%d/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

or similar. This have two problems. Substitution `%d` means whole home directory and `IdentityFile` option should get the private key, not the public one.

The reason why it asks for passphrase is described in this [upstream bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522) (in short, OpenSSH does not validate the errors returned from OpenSSL and every error interprets as a bad passphrase) and it should be fixed in the next update.

Or you might have some similar alias trying to use this key? What is the output of `type ssh`?