# OpenSSH prompts for password for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` which is already in ssh-agent

Tags: openssh, ssh-agent

When I attempt to SSH to a host, `ssh` still prompts for the password of the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key (Which was generated and exported from PuTTYgen), even though the password is already loaded in `ssh-agent` (I checked with `ssh-add -l` and `ssh-add -L`)

The `AddKeysToAgent yes` is present in the relevant `/etc/ssh/ssh-config` or `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Pre-empt flaggers that scan through things quickly: No, it is not a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290166/28015, read and compare the filenames

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-agent` does not keep track of the filenames of the keys that is loaded into it.

If the key is encrypted, `ssh` does not know if it matches the key that is already loaded, since it needs to decrypt it first.

To prevent the double prompt, ensure that the public key, in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is present as well. `ssh` can use this to determine that the key is already loaded to prevent the unnecessary prompt.